# Get the class in which an enum is declared

Tags: java, enums

This is a Java question regarding enum.

I have these classes:

```
class Test{
    public static enum TestEnum implements Variable{
        TEST_SOMETHING
        ;
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //how to get class Object Test from var?
        Variable var = TestEnum.TEST_SOMETHING;

    }
}
```

So, how do I get the Class object `Test` from the variable `Variable` with the value `Test.TestEnum.TEST_SOMETHING`?

Comment: Call `toString()`? If you're modelling behaviour perhaps your should add some kind of methods to the `Variable` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection like so:

```
Class<?> testClass = TestEnum.TEST_SOMETHING.getClass().getDeclaringClass();
```

The call to `getClass()` returns a class object describing the `TestEnum` enum, as this is the "class" of `TEST_SOMETHING`. The ensuing call to `getDeclaringClass()` returns `Test`, as `Test` is the class in which `TestEnum` declared (its *declaring class*).

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is the complete documentation of `java.lang.Class`, which will be the starting point for practically any reflective operation.